# how to display data with ajax in diffrent dom elements?

Tags: php, ajax

i want to display data that the Ajax function receive from php file into different HTML elements.

```
function getdetails(x)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("fname").value=xmlhttp.responseText;

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'GET', 
   url:'url/to/the/file.php',
}.done(function( msg ) {
   $('#id-of-element').html(msg);
   $('.class-of-other-element').html(msg); // another element
   $('.class-of-another-element').html(msg); // another element
});
```

Explanation:

```
type: GET // type of http request to the file, could also be POST 

url: 'url/to/the/file.php' // provide the file and path to file to communicate with

.done (function(msg)) {  // when ajax request is completed (if), then assign the variable 'msg' with the contents of the return.

$('#id-of-element').html(msg); // assign the return data to the html element of your choice.
```

EDIT:

If you're expecting 2 variables, in the PHP file return them like this:

```
echo $var1."/".$var2  // where '/' is a symbol you never expect to be returned in either variable.
```

Then in your Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'GET', 
   url:'url/to/the/file.php',
}.done(function( msg ) {
   var content = msg; 
   var varSplit = msg.split('/'); //where '/' is the symbol you chose to use in the stage above.
   var var1     = varSplit[0];
   var var2     = varSplit[1];
   $('.first-element').html(var1);
   $('.second-element').html(var2);
});
```

Comment: but i want to display that data into multiple elements not in single element like text-box,text-area etc.

Comment: yes,thank you,but if i get variable 1 and 2 as a response then i want to display variable 1 in One-element and variable 2 in another second-element and not the whole response in both elements.

Comment: Do you know what the response will be?